# Cell references/formulas in Excel to other workbooks on Sharepoint don't update values

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

## The problem

I have eight Excel documents that are stored on a Sharepoint site. One of those documents (**“receiving file”**) contains formulas/cell references to the other seven documents (“**source files**”) on Sharepoint.

Everything works when the references are created.

Once the workbooks are saved and closed and then reopened, the receiving file no longer updates the values from the source files.

The files are synced in Windows Explorer and opened in the desktop version of Excel. Also, all eight files are opened at the same time.

The reference will first look something like this

```
='[Source file.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

After closing and reopening, the references will look like this

```
='https://somecompanyname.sharepoint.com/sites/SitefortestingExcelreferences/Shared Documents/[Source file.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

If I now change a value in the source value, the change will not appear in the receiving file.

## What I tried so far

1. Setting “Calculation” to “Automatic.
2. Click “Calculate Now” and “Calculate Sheet”.
3. Double-click into the cell with the reference and hit enter.
4. In “Data > Queries & Connections” click “Refresh all”
5. In “Data > Queries & Connections > Edit Link” I clicked on update values. It did not help. However, I tried to rebuild a simple system with just two files and a single reference, and here it did work

Starting from point 5) I programmed a little macro that updates all links in all open workbooks (it did not help either):

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateAllConnections()

    Dim wbWorkbook As Workbook
    
    For Each wbWorkbook In Application.Workbooks
        wbWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=wbWorkbook.LinkSources, Type:=xlExcelLinks
    Next wbWorkbook
    
    MsgBox "Update complete.", vbInformation, "Complete"
End Sub
```

If I remove the path to SharePoint, so the formula looks like this

```
='[Source file.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

It works again (until I save and reopen).

I found the following on Microsoft Answers (about OneDrive but it's probably the same issue):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-value-links-not-updating-on-onedrive/e48a7680-71e6-4a77-9eb1-e03ec7f0e3e0

> I contacted the official O365 support desk and they told me this is built into the connection between Excel and OneDrive.
> They have received thousands of complaints and there is no fix for it.
> No option to tell Excel/Office/OneDrive to link to local copies of files on 1D by default.
> No fix is planned as this is not how MS envisions how Excel/1D should be used.

## My question

Any suggestions? Are there any tools in Excel that can be used to update the linked cells automatically or manually? Might SharePoint settings prevent the update?

If not, since removing the file path to SharePoint seems to work is there a way (using VBA) to remove the full file path from all cell references, so

```
='https://somecompanyname.sharepoint.com/sites/SitefortestingExcelreferences/Shared Documents/[Source file.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

becomes

```
='[Source file.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

I could probably loop through all cells and simply replace the path with nothing, but that would only work if I know the file path beforehand and if all the files are stored in the same SharePoint folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and here is my workaround: I can open the source file on the Sharepoint site by clicking `...` and then `Open in App` (as opposed to `Open in Browser`) The referecence cell in the receiving file will become `='[Source file.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1` again and get automatically updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As I see it, that does not fix my issue. I am already opening the Excel files in the desktop app (I have the SharePoint site synchronized in File Explorer, so I open them the same way as all other Excel files).

Answer (score 0):

My workaround would be to consolidate external links onto a single sheet, and manually or use a macro to copy / hard paste to another identical page that you use for the links.

Just run the macro when you have the workbook open on your desktop to update the values.

Even simpler, you could also have a sort of database with linked values in a column and hard copies pasted into another column.  This would be simpler than two identically sized sheets.

BUT, you could also go crazy and have named ranges like `quarterly_total_formula` and an analogue somewhere else called `quarterly_total_valueonly` and then write a macro to iterate over each with a for each looking for things "LIKE" `*_formula` and hard paste each result into the complementary `*_valueonly` spot... but then you'd need a macro to check that they were all paired... and by that point you might as well not waste your time in Excel and develop in Power BI, Tableau, RMarkdown, or heck learn Adobe Illustrator or work directly in HTML.